# ng-keypress event is not getting fired when - or . are pressed on the numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, keypress, keyboard-events

i have an input field with type = number and a function listening to the keypress event.  Function gets called for all keypresses except - (minus) and . (decimal point).

the input field -

```
<input type = "number" ng-keypress = "vm.keypressed($event)" ng-model ="vm.inputNumber"/>
```

The function

```
vm.keypressed = function(e){
   var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
   console.log(charCode);
}
```

However, this function is not getting called for - and . while it is for all other key presses.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

my guess its because of the data type number change the data type and try again

Comment: But i need to use type="number" to get the number keyboard.